# Load local .osm file to display/plot a map

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, openstreetmap, local

I have exported a map part from the openstreetmap.org website and stored the "map.osm" file localy.

Now, I am trying to load this file into R and plot the map as a background map layer.

However, I cannot find any osm (I have searched the documentation of rosm, osmdata, OpenStreetMap, and osmar) or ggplot/ggplot2 or ggmap/map package that supports a local .osm file as the map source.

Also, I could not find any tutorial or thread to just plot/display a local .osm file/tile.

---- Update:

So far the suggestion of @mpadge does not work. Here is what I have tried so far, and the compiler's answer:

```
library(osmdata)
osmdata::osmdata_sf(doc="map.osm")
```

Which yields:

```
Error in rcpp_osmdata_sf(doc) : way can not be found
```

Without quotes:

```
osmdata::osmdata_sf(doc=map.osm)
Error in fill_overpass_data(obj, doc, quiet = quiet) : 
  object 'map.osm' not found
```

Without "doc=" and quotes:

```
osmdata::osmdata_sf(map.osm)
Error in is(q, "overpass_query") : object 'map.osm' not found
```

And last:

```
osmdata::osmdata_sf("map.osm")
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle): Could not resolve host: 

overpass.kumi.systems
    Request failed [ERROR]. Retrying in 1.4 seconds...
```

Comment: Maybe this [osmar: OpenStreetMap and R](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/eugster-schlesinger.pdf) helps, cp. pp. 59-60.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: osmdata::osmdata_sf(doc=*.osm) will work, or use osmextract for general-purpose importing tools and useful tools for downloading OSM data. (osmar has been abandoned, and is no longer usable.)